# Probability of stay in matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix, probability

You are given a matrix of order (M x N). You can move in 4 directions: left, top, right and bottom. You are given initial position (x, y) and number of steps which you can move from the given location. While moving if you go out of the matrix, you are disqualified from the game. What is the probability that you are not disqualified?

I solved the question in the following two ways:

Way 1. Find out total ways say T1 in which you will be inside the matrix and find out total ways T2 in which you will be out of the matrix. Then return T1 / (T1 + T2) as the result.

Way 2. Use the fact that probability of reaching your neighbor is: 1/4 as you can move only in 4 directions from the given position and calculate the result.

But the two approaches are giving different results in many scenarios.

Please find my code below and do let me know where I am mistaken or if there is fault in the approaches.

```
public class ProbabilityOfStay {

    private int[] x = {0, 1, 0, -1};
    private int[] y = {-1, 0, 1, 0};

    private int ROW;
    private int COL;
    private int xPos;
    private int yPos;
    private int steps ;
    int[][][] stayDP = null;
    int[][][] nonStayDP = null;
    float[][][] sp = null;

    public ProbabilityOfStay(int R, int C, int x, int y, int steps)
    {
        this.ROW = R;
        this.COL = C;

        this.xPos = x;
        this.yPos = y;
        this.steps = steps;

        stayDP = new int[ROW][COL][steps];
        nonStayDP = new int[ROW][COL][steps];
        sp = new float[ROW][COL][steps];

        this.initializeInt(stayDP, -1);
        this.initializeInt(nonStayDP, -1);
        this.initializeF(sp, -1);   
    }

    private void initializeInt(int[][][] M, int d)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < COL; j++)
            {
                for(int k = 0; k < steps; k++)
                    M[i][j][k] = d;
            }
        }
    }

    private void initializeF(float[][][] M, int d)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < COL; j++)
            {
                for(int k = 0; k < steps; k++)
                    M[i][j][k] = d;
            }
        }
    }

    private int getTotalStayPath()
    {
        int p = getStayPaths(xPos, yPos, steps);

        return p;
    }

    private int getStayPaths(int xp, int yp, int s)
    {
        if(xp < 0 || xp >= ROW || yp < 0 || yp >= COL)
            return 0;

        if(s == 0)
            return 1;

        if(stayDP[xp][yp][s-1] != -1)
            return stayDP[xp][yp][s-1];

        int ans = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
        {
            ans += getStayPaths(xp + x[i], yp + y[i], s-1);
        }

        return (stayDP[xp][yp][s-1] = ans);
    }

    private int getTotalNonStayPath()
    {
        int p = getNonStayPaths(xPos, yPos, steps);

        return p;
    }

    private int getNonStayPaths(int xp, int yp, int s)
    {
        if(xp < 0 || xp >= ROW || yp < 0 || yp >= COL)
            return 1;

        if(s == 0)
            return 0;

        if(nonStayDP[xp][yp][s-1] != -1)
            return nonStayDP[xp][yp][s-1];

        int ans = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
        {
            ans += getNonStayPaths(xp + x[i], yp + y[i], s - 1);
        }

        return (nonStayDP[xp][yp][s-1] = ans);
    }

    private float getStayProbabilityM()
    {
        float p = getProbability(xPos, yPos, steps);

        return p;
    }

    private float getProbability(int xp, int yp, int s)
    {
        if(xp < 0 || xp >= ROW || yp < 0 || yp >= COL)
            return 0;

        if(s == 0)
            return 1;

        if(sp[xp][yp][s-1] != -1)
            return sp[xp][yp][s-1];

        float ans = 0.0f;

        for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
        {
            ans += (getProbability(xp + x[i], yp + y[i], s-1)) / 4.0;
        }

        return (sp[xp][yp][s-1] = ans);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int ROW = 7, COL = 7, x = 3, y = 5, steps = 3; //(x, y) is your position in the matrix.
        ProbabilityOfStay pos = new ProbabilityOfStay(ROW, COL, x, y, steps);

        int totalStayPaths = pos.getTotalStayPath(); //number of ways in which you can stay in the matrix.
        int totalNonStayPaths = pos.getTotalNonStayPath(); ////number of ways in which you can't stay in the matrix.

        float stayingProbability = (totalStayPaths / (float)(totalStayPaths + totalNonStayPaths));

        float sP_memorization = pos.getStayProbabilityM();

        System.out.println("Total stay paths: " + totalStayPaths + ", total non-stay paths: " + totalNonStayPaths + ", Stay probability: " + stayingProbability);

        System.out.println("Total probability memoriation: " + sP_memorization);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I run the program it prints:

```
Total stay paths: 56, total non-stay paths: 5
```

However, this results in a total number of paths of 56+5=61.

There are 4 choices at each of 3 steps, so the total should be 4*4*4 = 64.

I think the issue is that you stop counting as soon as the path goes off the board.  This means that the paths are not of equal probability so your calculation by dividing the number of paths is not valid.

If you change the computation to:

```
float stayingProbability = (totalStayPaths / (float)Math.pow(4,steps));
```

it prints matching answers.

Comment: Yes you are correct. The expression that I used to to calculate the probability is wrong. Your one is correct. Thanks.